# magazine epaper app pdf in uiwebview - app crashes

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I have developed a magazine e paper app which opens the PDF files in UIWebView. I have created a set of 3 webviews at a time & display the PDF pages to handle smooth scrolling. When loading some pages or zooming the app crashes & unable to track the crash. It happens only in the client's iPad & doesn't happens in our iPad. But I get the following errors displayed in the LOG continually.

```
ePaper[576] <Error>: FAFONG+Helvetica: FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 6.
ePaper[576] <Error>: FAFOOH+TimesNewRomanPSMT: FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 6.
ePaper[576] <Error>: FAFONG+Helvetica: FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 6.
ePaper[576] <Error>: FAFOOH+TimesNewRomanPSMT: FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 6.


JJBOOI+DixielandPSMT: FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 38.
ePaper[576] <Error>: JJEANE+STMZH---040: FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 6.
ePaper[576] <Error>: JJDADE+ITRFK-Tam7-PalmleafM-Bold-Bold: FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 6.
```

Can anyone guide me?